# Java code explanation - short

Tags: java

could someone kindly add some comments too this to explain its process. I'm confused how the `(a.compareTo(b)<=0)` functions.

```
public class step31 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Number
        String a = "AB";
        String b = "AC";
        String c = "AD";
        String d = "";
        if(a.compareTo(b)<=0) // using compareTo to compare between two strings, it return a number, if the number <=0 then a less than b
        {
            if(c.compareTo(a)<=0)
            {
                d = "'c'<='a'<='b'";
            }
            else if(b.compareTo(c)<=0)
            {
                d = "'a'<='b'<='c'";
            }
            else
            {
                d = "'a'<='c'<='b'";
            }
        }
        // a>b
        else
        {
            if(a.compareTo(c)<=0)
            {
                d = "'b'<='a'<='c'";
            }
            else if(c.compareTo(b)<=0)
            {
                d = "'c'<='b'<='a'";
            }
            else
            {
                d = "'b'<='c'<='a'";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(d);

    }

}
```

Some comments would be appreciated.

Comment: why not check the sdk about String ?

Comment: What are you confused about?  The javadoc documentation, the code for compareTo?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the javadoc related to [compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

> Compares two strings lexicographically. The comparison is based on the
>   Unicode value of each character in the strings. The character sequence
>   represented by this String object is compared lexicographically to the
>   character sequence represented by the argument string. The result is a
>   negative integer if this String object lexicographically precedes the
>   argument string. The result is a positive integer if this String
>   object lexicographically follows the argument string. The result is
>   zero if the strings are equal; compareTo returns 0 exactly when the
>   equals(Object) method would return true.  This is the definition of
>   lexicographic ordering. If two strings are different, then either they
>   have different characters at some index that is a valid index for both
>   strings, or their lengths are different, or both. If they have
>   different characters at one or more index positions, let k be the
>   smallest such index; then the string whose character at position k has
>   the smaller value, as determined by using the < operator,
>   lexicographically precedes the other string. In this case, compareTo
>   returns the difference of the two character values at position k in
>   the two string -- that is, the value:
>
> this.charAt(k)-anotherString.charAt(k)   If there is no index
>   position at which they differ, then the shorter string
>   lexicographically precedes the longer string. In this case, compareTo
>   returns the difference of the lengths of the strings -- that is, the
>   value:   this.length()-anotherString.length()
>
> the value 0 if the argument string is equal to this string; a value
>   less than 0 if this string is lexicographically less than the string
>   argument; and a value greater than 0 if this string is
>   lexicographically greater than the string argument.

from java doc

Answer (score 0):

`a.compareTo(b) <= 0` means `a <= b`, i.e. true if `a` is the same as `b` or earlier when sorting alphabetically. (Using comparators like `<=` is illegal for anything except numbers in Java, which is why the `compareTo` method is needed.)

Likewise, `a.compareTo(b) >  0` would be interpreted like `a > b`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an IDE, such as Eclipse, that allows you to step into code.  For instance, in Eclipse, you can select the method, then hit "f3" and you will jump into the method you are wondering about.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_compareto.htm - an excellent tutorial on the compare to method

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String) - javadocs java 7 String class check the compare to method

The return from the method

`The value 0 if the argument is a string lexicographically equal to this string; a value less than 0 if the argument is a string lexicographically greater than this string; and a value greater than 0 if the argument is a string lexicographically less than this string.`

hope this gives you some pointers